# OpenLayers3 Not Displaying Image

Tags: asp.net, openlayers-3

I am writing a map application using openlayers3. I am upgrading from openlayers2 which works well. My issue is that the image returned from my wms server is not displaying in the div. The image returned is a png image. I know it returns a correct image because I save it in my api call to the WMS server as well as check the debugging tools in my browser and the image shows up, returned as a "image/png". I also have a div with id="map" and I set the width and height of the div. The zoom in and zoom out controls show up for the map but the actual image does not.

Code:

```
        map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Image({
                extent: parameters.maxExtent,
                source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                    url: '../../WMS/floorplan?',
                    params: { 'LAYERS': '@Model.LayerName', 'VERSION': '1.3.0', 'FORMAT': "image/png", 'SHAPEFILE': '@Model.ShapeFile'},
                    ratio: 0.8,
                    serverType: 'mapserver'
                })
            })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            projection: '@Model.Projection',
            center: [@Model.CenterLon, @Model.CenterLat],
            extent: parameters.maxExtent,
            zoom: 0.5
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems setting a ratio on the ImageWMS source that is less than one causes this. See http://jsfiddle.net/zL9jhgqf/ (setting ratio to one and running it again makes it work).

```
source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
  url: 'http://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/wms',
  params: {'LAYERS': 'topp:states'},
  ratio: 0.8,
  serverType: 'geoserver'
})
```

I created an issue about it, since I don't know what the expected behaviour is: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3926

BTW. What is the use case for having a WMS layer covering less than the viewport?

Comment: The reason I had to lower the ratio so much was because when I retrieve the image with no ratio set it returns xml with the error message "Width is too large". Changing the ratio was the only way I knew how to modify the width. I tried setting the width in the parameters for the call but after searching around it seems OL3 sets them dynamically when doing an imagewms call

Comment: If a WMS does not support the width and height of your map viewport, it may be better to use ol.source.TileWMS. Using a ratio less than 1 does not make much sense.

Comment: I tried using the TileWMS but it never makes the call to the URL. In the above code I swap Image for Tile and ImageWMS for TileWMS and remove ratio. Using the network tools in my browser shows the call to ../../WMS/floorplan never gets called

Comment: ol3 supports tiled WMS: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/examples/wms-tiled.html Open a new question if you want help using it.